# File Creation on Nodejs without CRLF line terminators

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, fs

I have two identical files when I compare them as string. But sizes are different and filetytes are also different when I ask it like below.

```
$ file ~/Desktop/gprs
ASCII text

$ file ~/Desktop/2/gprs
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I created first one with Ubuntu > New Document > Empty Document section.
I created second file from NodeJs with fs plugin like below :

```
fs.writeFile("/2/gprs", data, function(error) {

      if (error) {

        console.log(error);

      } else {

        console.log("Ok");
      }
});
```

I want second file without CRLF line terminators option. How can I create it with that way ?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is probably more about the contents of the `data` variable than an issue with the `writeFile`.  How did you get/construct the data that caused it to have CRLF?

Comment: Your data in node js contains line endings "\r\n" simply use `data.replace('\r\n', '\n');`

Comment: Actually the problem was that. I use var os = require('os'); os.EOL for line endings. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var os = require('os'); os.EOL` solved my problem

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var os = require('os')
...
    fs.writeFile(fileName, fileContent, { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'w', EOL: os.EOL }, function (err) {
         if (err) {
              console.error('Error writing to the file:', err);
         } else {
              console.log('File written successfully');
         }
    });
```